# Mock an array in a Componet class Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

How to mock an array in Angular test

**component.ts**

```
//variable declaration
certificatelist: any[] = [];
getCert(certificatename:any){
for (let index1 in this.certificatelist) {
//do some action
}
```

}

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('should be able to show default certdropdown after upload',()=>{
      let certificateName='TestCert';
      component.getCert(certificateName);
      //do the condition check
})
```

In this case when i tried to run the test ,its getting failed because of this.certificatelist is empty.
how can we mok the this.certificatelist

Answer (score 0):

pass the `certificatelist` as parameter,

then create a mock to pass to the method when you call it from your test

Comment: can u please give a sample

Comment: `
getCert(certificatename:any, certificatelist:[]){

for (let index1 in this.certificatelist) {

//do some action

}

`

[...]

`
mock = []; // here import your mock in somehow, ie from an external json file

it('should be able to show default certdropdown after upload',()=>{

      let certificateName='TestCert';

      component.getCert(certificateName, mock);


      //do the condition check

})
`